# Loop through folder with monthly reports, apply filter and copy to master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I've made it this far with some existing stack-overflow answers to similar questions but now I seem to be stuck. What I want to do is to loop through a folder with workbooks named "XXX-statistics201XXX.xls" and open each of them. Then apply a filter (or loop to match strings) to one of the columns in worksheet 3 and copy the values in the columns to the left and right of it. These should then be copied to a workbook (in my case the workbook containing the macro but that was mostly to simplify it), together with the year and month of the workbook which probably has to be taken from the last 4 figures in its filename. I tried solving this with the following code, but it just says "the sub 'Search' cannot be found". What object does the search method belong to?

```
    dotindex = Search(".", Item.Name)
    ReportDate = Mid(Item.Name, dotindex - 4, 4)
```

[Here was a problem that was fixed by Graffl, edited out to save space]

I realize there are many different questions in one here but any help for one of the "steps" would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Collectdata()
Dim c As Range

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
Set callwbk = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Iterate through the files in the folder
For Each Item In objFiles
  If LCase(Right(Item.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Or LCase(Right(Item.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Then
        If Item.Name <> callwbk.Name Then
        Set usewbk = Application.Workbooks.Open(Item.Name)
        On Error Resume Next
        usewbk.Sheets(3).Activate
        SearchColumn = usewbk.Sheets(3).Cells.Find(What:="HRSSystem").Column
             'For Each c In Columns(SearchColumn) *<-- Why doesn't this work?*
             For Each c In usewbk.Sheets(3).Range("C:C")
                If c.Value = "SEARCHTERM" Then
                c.Offset(0, 1).Copy Paste:=callwbk.Sheets(3).Cells(c.Row, 6) 'Just to test, a better  destination could be used
                c.Offset(0, -1).Copy Paste:=callwbk.Sheets(3).Cells(c.Row, 8)
                End If
             Next c
        End If
   End If
   If usewbk <> Null Then
   usewbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
   End If
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following things and try again:

- To open an Workbook you need the full path to it and not just the name `Application.Workbooks.Open(Item.Path)`
- Copy and paste are two separate commands and you have to use `PasteSpecial`.

  ```
  c.Offset(0, 1).Copy 
  callwbk.Sheets(3).Cells(c.Row, 6).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
  ```
- Using `SearchColumn` doesn't work because it returns the number of the column (integer) and not the range. But you could use something like:

  ```
  usewbk.Sheets(3).Range("A:A").Offset(0, SearchColumn - 1).Cells
  ```
- And you definitely should put the file with the code outside the folder with the files that yuo want to run through and use something like: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Subfolder"`

Comment: Man this forum is awesome, thourough answers within an hour. And your suggestions made the opening of the workbooks work again (I have no idea how it could work before cause I'm pretty sure I never changed to item.name from item.path). I also added a subfolder, which is probably nice although I think my "Item.Name <> callwbk.Name" handled that.

However, I still can't copy anything to the workbook - I just loop through the reports but nothing happens to the "callwbk". Also, how do I conveniently loop through "(0, SearchColumn - 1)" conveniently as a range, similar to what I have now?

Comment: Yes, right. The past method also needs to change still. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks, now I managed to loop through the folder and import most of the stuff I was looking for. All of a sudden it can't find "usewkb" though and I have no idea why really - "Object 424 can't be found" or something similar".
I'll try to sort it out and I'm on a good way thanks to the help but it's really frustrating!